# merging 4 files into 1 file with different columns

Tags: bash, shell

i have 4 files : t1.rg t2.rg t3.rg t4.rg 
    `t1.rg contains Fri Aug  3 19:48:58 MYT 2018
     t2.rg contains 27
     t3.rg contains A-inter-rt01
     t4.rg contains 32166`

i have tried with this :
    `pr -mts t1.rg t3.rg t2.rg t4.rg`

but it comes up something like this :

```
`Fri Aug 32166:48:58 MYT 2018    A-inter-rt01 27`
```

Also tried using :
    
    `value1=$(cat t1.rg)
    value2=$(cat t3.rg)
    value3=$(cat t2.rg)
    value4=$(cat t4.rg)`

```
`value5=$(paste <printf "%s" "$value1" <printf "%s" "$value2" <printf "%s" 
"$value3" <printf "%s" "$value4")
 `
```

but it some how dosent work at all for me .

output should be something like this :

```
 `Fri Aug  3 19:48:58 MYT 2018 |  27   | A-inter-rt01  | 32166`
```

i'm struck and new to scripting, please help

Comment: why would pr not work??? its working fine with me

Comment: Please note that you format code by selecting it with the mouse and clicking the `{}` button in the formatting toolbar - just to the right of `Bold` and `Italic`.

Answer (score 3):

simply make use of `paste`:

```
 paste f1 f3 f2 f4
```

If you want "pipe" to be the delimiter, you can use `-d` option.